# Confirm message - stop to process if user click NO

Tags: javascript, html

I have "confirm" alert inside the HTML

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\" class='btn btn-danger btn-xs disConBtn'><i class='fa fa-unlink'></i></a>
```

If I click "NO" it's still run the ajax script.
How do I stop to process if user click NO inside the dialog message/alert?

Comment: What do you mean by ajax script. In this code it does nothing. Can you provide reproducible code, so that others can understand your problem.

Comment: Assuming you have an event handler on the `disConBtn` you just need to move the confirm to there

Answer (score 0):

Your confirm method doesnot stop the form submission. You have to place confirm inside the Javascript.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
            do something
        } else {
            do nothing
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you do that inside the <a href></a> tag?

Comment: No, You cannot place "Confirm()" seperately in <a> tag. It has to be placed in the same script where ajax request has to be processed. You have to set event handler to submit button and onsubmit the script will ask for confirmation. If confirmed, it will process.